# Retrieving WooCommerce Cart Session Using Cart Hash from Local Storage for Both Logged-In and Guest Users?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I wanted to create a Rest API which gets requests which will take the WooCommerce cart hash value from session storage and return cart data and user data in response.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Cart API
*/

// Register custom REST API endpoints
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    // Endpoint to retrieve cart data by cart hash
    register_rest_route('custom-cart/v1', '/cart/(?P<cart_hash>\w+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_cart_data_by_hash',
        'permission_callback' => function () {
            // Implement your own authentication logic here
            // For example, check if the user is logged in
            return is_user_logged_in();
        }
    ));
});

// Callback function to retrieve cart data by hash
function get_cart_data_by_hash($request) {
    $cart_hash = $request['cart_hash'];

    // Retrieve cart data based on the cart hash
    // Implement your own logic to retrieve cart data
    // For example, you might query the database or use session storage
    $cart_data = get_cart_data_from_session($cart_hash);

    if ($cart_data) {
        return rest_ensure_response($cart_data);
    } else {
        return new WP_Error('cart_not_found', 'Cart not found', array('status' => 404));
    }
}

// Function to retrieve cart data from session storage
function get_cart_data_from_session($cart_hash) {
    // Implement your logic to retrieve cart data from session storage
    // For example, if you're using PHP sessions:
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$cart_hash])) {
        return $_SESSION['cart'][$cart_hash];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

expecting result is an object where the user cart session will return in response.

Comment: So what does your current code? Is there any issue with it?